# Is it bad to have MaterialApp's home be a MaterialApp?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a multi-page application, and currently have this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
      title: "App", debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: HomePage()));
}
```

And over in HomePage, I return a Material App

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(); //My home page
  }
}
```

I looked online for if the home property of a MaterialApp should return another MaterialApp, as HomePage currently does, or if it should return a Scaffold, and I couldn't really find anything. I would think that a Scaffold makes a bit more sense, since that's what I would typically do in a single-page app, but the only thing that gives me pause is that in terms of syntax, making a new "MaterialApp" for each page and changing which is displayed sounds pretty nice-but I could very well be wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A material app is used to define theme, route etc. So for the whole app it is good to have just one material app. Define all themes etc in it and have all other classes return a scaffold that way you have better control over the app..

More about material app
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html

More about scaffold

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't recommend you to have two `MaterialApp` widgets, since you set properties in the first `MaterialApp`, meaning that the BuildContext of Flutter will not get those properties since there is a second `MaterialApp` widget lower in the widget tree.

What I would recommend you, is to directly pass your `HomePage` widget in the `runApp` function. That will allow you more clarity and visibility of your widgets:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "App", debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: HomePage())
  }
}
```

Then, in `HomePage` and all other pages that are views, you can return a `Scaffold`.